# GIT diff and GIT status ignore changes of a file

Tags: git, diff, status

I have a git repository which I worked with for some weeks. It contains branches.
Now I have the problem that I edit a specific file (which I added a long time ago) but the new version doesn't appear in `git diff` nor in `git status`. So I can't commit new versions of this file.

This doesn't happen for all my files.

What could be the problem here?

EDIT:

- My `.gitignore` is empty.
- The specific file is located in the main directory.

Comment: you can try 'git revert file_name' on that file from the branch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for me was

```
git update-index --really-refresh
```

Comment: I like the fact that git has options like `--really-refresh` for saying "Yes, I know what I am doing. Just DO IT" :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you added your file in the `.gitignore` file which reside in the root directory of your project.

Remove the file from `.gitignore` file and you will see the file changes by `git status` command.

Comment: Or you can `git add -f the_file`  force add the file you want to track to git (then you will see all diff/update after that)

Comment: No, that's unfortunately not the case. I just commented everything in .gitignore out.

Comment: @AlexanderBuchner how you comment the line?

Comment: With a '#' at the start of every line.

Comment: then are you getting the .gitignore as modified? make sure the file you modified is under the project folder

Comment: Yes, .gitignore is now marked as modified and I see many untracked files, of course. And git add fileName doesn't output anything.

Comment: Then please explain you question by putting the project folder map and file or with some other detail

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.gitignore` file, you might find that file there. If you will. just delete it from there, should work.

[Gitignore file info](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Comment: No, that's unfortunately not the case. I just commented everything in .gitignore out.